# Rails 3 - link_to to call partial using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get a **link_to** to display a partial via jquery ajax, but can't seem to get it to work (edit: returning blank screen) and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

I would like to click the link "Preview Widget" and have it display **_widget.html.erb** in the div **preview**.

From my understanding the link "Preview Widget" should call the action **def preview_widget** which calls **preview_widget.js.erb** which then renders the partial **_widget.html.erb** in the div.

**EDIT:** updates link as per Ignatius Reza suggestions

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Preview Widget", :action => 'preview_widget' , :id => @widget.id, :remote => true %> %>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

**widget_controller.rb**

```
def preview_widget  
    respond_to do | format |  
        format.js {render :layout => false}  
    end
end
```

**preview_widget.js.erb**

```
$( "#preview" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => "widget", :locals => { :widget => @widget} ) ) %>" );
```

**_widget.html.erb**

```
<% @widget.videos.each do |video| %>
      <h3><a href='#'><%= video.name %></a></h3>
      <div>
        <object height='316' width='540'>
          <embed  style='border: 1px solid #333333;' height='316' width='540' allowfullscreen='true' allowscriptaccess='always' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' src='<%= video.url %>'>
        </object>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
match 'preview_widget' => 'widgets#preview_widget'
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok finally got this to work with the following changes.
**routes.rb** (added member to widget resources)

```
  resources :widgets do
    member do
      get 'preview_widget'
    end
  end
```

**show.html.erb** (changed link_to to match routes)

```
<%= link_to 'Preview', preview_widget_widget_path(:id => @widget.id),  :remote => true %>
```

This now shows the partial. I am still not 100% sure what was wrong with the previous code - at least it now works.

Answer (score 5):

It's not cleared on your question, what you "can't seem to get it to work".. but from what i see in the code you gave.. all seems right, but you miss the actual ajax call..

it could be added by adding :remote => true to the "Preview Widget" link such as :

```
<%= link_to "Preview Widget", :action => 'preview_widget' , :id => @widget, :remote => true %>
```

if the default behaviour is enough.. or you could add your own custom ajax call on application.js..

as a note, i don't think setting the :id attribute of "Preview Widget" link to @widget is wise.. as it will put the string representation of widget, which usually will looks like "<Widget:0x12412 ..>" perhaps it would be better to change it to "widget-link-#{@widget.id}"

Comment: Thanks. I have added the :remote => true to the code and fixed widget-link-#{@widget.id}. The link is now "http://localhost:3000/preview_widget?id=1&remote=true" when I click on it I get blank page?

Comment: which version of rails did you used? i'm assuming that you used 3.* when i suggest adding ":remote => true".. as starting in 3.0, rails used unobtrusive javascipt approach to handle all javascript related feature.. if you're using 2.*.. then you need to change link_to to remote_link_to, and optionally remove the ":remote => true"..

Answer (score 4):

I’ve a similar problem that brought me to this threat, so I thought sharing my solution here might be helpful to anybody.

With `:remote => true` I got an normal HTTP Request to `http://localhost:3000/info/about?remote=true` instead of the wanted AJAX Request to `http://localhost:3000/info/about`

The fix was easy but hard to find!

**In my HAML View:**

WRONG Code that triggers HTTP Request

```
= link_to( image_tag("icons/information.png", :title => t('menu.info')), :controller => "info", :action => "about", :remote => true )
```

OK-Code that triggers AJAX Request

```
= link_to( image_tag("icons/information.png", :title => t('menu.info')), {:controller => "info", :action => "about"}, :remote => true )
```

**The only difference is {curly brackets}!**

Funny though is that with the AJAX Request I get `info/about.html` rendered, without the layout file. Which isn’t a partial but is close to what Jan wanted.
I was expecting `info/about.js.erb` to be rendered.

**In InfoController**

```
  def about
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # renders ‘views/info/about.html.erb’ inside layout template on HTTP Request
      format.js# renders ‘views/info/about.html.erb’, without layout
    end
  end
```

-

```
  def about
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # => ‘views/info/about.html.erb’ inside layout template on HTTP Request
      format.js {render 'about.js'} # => renders ‘views/info/about.js.erb’
    end
  end
```