# Render a partial in rails using jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I am trying to setup a navigation bar on my home page that loads a partial into a div element when the user clicks on the links. I have followed the steps in this post and modified them as I thought I needed:
[Rails 3 - link_to to call partial using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766383/rails-3-link-to-to-call-partial-using-jquery-ajax)

My code:

**views/pages/home.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to "Files", :action => 'load_upload_partial', :remote => true %>
```

.
.
.

```
<div id="main_frame"></div>
```

**pages_controller:**

```
def load_upload_partial  
    respond_to do | format |  
      format.js {render :layout => false}  
    end
end
```

**/views/uploads/load_upload_partial.js.erb:**

```
$("#main_frame").html( "<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => "/upload/upload_form" ) %>" );
```

The partial in this example is just a form. When I click on the link I get a blank page with this is the address bar:
http://localhost:3000/load_upload_partial?remote=true

This makes me think that link is not triggering an ajax GET request (if that's the correct terminology). If that is the case is there anything I need to be adding to my application.js file? I followed the railscast #136 on rails and jquery but couldn't figure out which bits of the application.js code applied to my case.
Any thoughts are much appreciated. Thanks. Tom

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? I can't say why, but the problem is Rails is including `:remote => true` in the `url_options` argument to `link_to`.

Comment: 3.0.7. Can't work out the link_to options for this version so any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I now tend to avoid using RJS like you're intending to. I prefer creating js templates with tools like handlebars.

I only use ajax to get raw data and then recreate the partial client side. It's much better for server load and data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your link_to to:

```
<%= link_to "Files", {:action => 'load_upload_partial' }, remote => true %>
```

The problem is related to the method signature of link_to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the link_to line to include { :remote => true } but it caused an exception on loading the page: /app/views/pages/home.html.erb:8: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC ...partial', { :remote => true } );@output_buffer.safe_concat(' I am using Rails 3.0.7 if that changes anything?

Comment: Sorry, I replied very quickly. I edited my reply and tried it. It should work now :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is still not working - the link is 'dead' but I am sending text/javascript now, which is progress. I am receiving a 500 internal server error so I guess that my js.erb file must be incorrect. Will have a proper root around on that one. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

ran into this same problem - the hint was in the malformed html produced - take a look at the value of the href attribute of the tag produced by your code. I bet it looks funky. Here's the correct code:

```
    <%= link_to "Files", your_path, action: 'load_upload_partial', remote: true %>
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using .load() instead of .html()?

Also, try using this line instead:

```
$("#main_frame").html( "<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => '/upload/upload_form' ) %>" );
```

Comment: downvotes should require an explanation... Otherwise I'm left with not know what is wrong with my suggestion.