# Rails 3 - How do I dynamically render a partial for a single object based on selected div using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple jquery auto complete search in my Rails 3 app based on the one in [Railscasts episode #240](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) that filters a list of location objects on the location index page by rendering a partial using jquery.

In the partial (**_locations.html.erb**), the location objects are each wrapped in their own div and are styled to look like a clickable element. When the user clicks one of them, I'd like it to do two things:

1. Change the selected div's background color to show that it's selected (this part already works fine).
2. Render content that's specific to the selected object in an empty div. A link to the show page will be included in the rendered content. This will basically function like a quickview/preview.

This all changes dynamically according to the current selection without refreshing the page.

#### My Problem:

I'm having troubles with the second point. I can't seem to get the partial to render when the location element is clicked. I've tried a lot of different things over the past week. There are a couple examples that have gotten me close ([Rails 3 - link_to to call partial using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766383/rails-3-link-to-to-call-partial-using-jquery-ajax), [Render a partial in rails using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901332/render-a-partial-in-rails-using-jquery)) in addition to many others that aren't as relevant but follow a similar strategy.

I suspect it might be a problem in the way I'm calling a partial within a partial, but I'm not sure. I included my code below. When I try it out, I'm taken to a blank page with the following address: localhost:3000/locations/1/show_quickview

Thanks for any help in advance. Also, thanks for helping me get this far - you guys are great!

**index.html.erb**

```rb
<%= form_tag locations_path, :method => 'get', :id => "locations_search" do %>
<p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
<div id="quickview"></div>     #placed here only for testing out
<div id="locations">
    <%= render 'locations' %>
</div>
```

**_locations.html.erb**

```rb
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
<div class="location">
    <h4><%= link_to location.name, show_quickview_location_path(:id => location.id), :remote => true %></h4>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**_quickview.html.erb**

```rb
<p><%= location.name %></p>     #keeping it simple for now
```

**routes.rb**

```rb
  resources :locations do
    member do
      get 'show_quickview'    
    end
  end
```

**locations_controller.rb**

```rb
  def show_quickview
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
```

**show_quickview.js.erb**

```rb
$("#quickview").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "quickview", :locals => { :location => location }))) %>");
```

**application.js**

```rb
$(function() {
  $("#locations_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#locations_search").attr("action"), $("#locations_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
    $(".location").click(function() {
        $(".location").not(this).removeClass('location-clicked h4');
        $(this).toggleClass('location-clicked h4');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well after stepping away from this problem for a while, I finally figured out the problems (there were multiple). Finally some closure!!

1. I had errors in the jquery code that render the partial.
2. I wasn't defining anything in my controller method.

The greatest thing I learned from this is the power of the server logs. If anyone runs into a similar issue, check your server logs - especially when debugging jquery. What a useful tool! Depending on what you are doing (like rendering a partial), rails might not render your error message in your browser, but it may still appear in your server logs. For me, it was tossing up an error related to my partial. Hopefully down the road this saves at least one person a bit of time.

Here's the final working code below. Please note that I changed some of the naming conventions and html structure too.

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag locations_path, :method => 'get', :id => "locations_search" do %>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>

<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="locations">
    <%= render 'locations' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="location-quickview">
    <h2>Select a Country...</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_locations.html.erb**

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
<div class="location">
  <h4><%= link_to location.name, quickview_location_path(:id => location.id), :remote => true %></h4>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**_quickview.html.erb**

```
<p><%= location.name %></p>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :locations do
  member do
    get 'quickview'    
  end
end
```

**locations_controller.html.erb**

```
def quickview
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do | format |  
    format.js {render :layout => false}  
  end
end
```

**quickview.js.erb**

```
$("#quickview").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "quickview", :locals => {:location => @location})) %>");
```