# How to get Rails 3 link_to :partial to work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

In my Rails app I want to have links in a user's Profile that `link_to` a `:partial` so that certain parts of the Profile aren't always loaded. I've looked at various articles and questions (mainly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766383/rails-3-link-to-to-call-partial-using-jquery-ajax)) but I can't get my `link_to` working. I currently get a routing error when I load Profiles#Show.

Below is my code. I'm a beginner so if anyone can help me figure out what's going on I'd appreciate it.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><%= link_to "Link 1", {:partial => 'a'}, {:class => "a"}, :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Link 2", {:partial => 'b'}, {:class => "a"}, :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Link 3", profile_profile_c_path(:id => @user.id), :remote => true %></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    # I want to load the partials in this div
  </div>
</div><!-- end tabs -->
```

I'm using the last `link_to` as an example:

```
<li><%= link_to "Link 3", profile_profile_c_path(:id => @user.id), :remote => true %></li>
```

**Here is my `routes.rb file:**

```
match "/profiles/:id/c" => "profiles#profile_c"
resources :profiles do
  get :profile_c
end
```

**Here is the `profile_c` action in `profiles_controller.rb`:**

```
def profile_c
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

**Here is my `profile_c.js.erb` file:**

```
$( "#tabs" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render (:partial => "c", :locals => { :id => @user.id } ) ) %>" );
```

**Here is my `_c.html.erb` partial:**

```
<% for object in @user.objects %>
<div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The error shows `No route matches {:action=>"profile_c", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>1}`

**UPDATE:** I no longer get an error. I changed my routes.rb to:

```
resources :profiles do
  get :profile_c, :on => :member
end
```

And my link_to to:

```
<li><%= link_to "Link 3", profile_c_profile_path(:id => @profile.id), :remote => true %></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

make your route like :

```
resources :profiles do
  get :profile_c, :on => :member
end
```

Comment: Still get `No route matches {:action=>"profile_c", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>1}`

Comment: Well if you write :on => :collection  instead of :on => :member ?

Comment: Where is your :action=>"profile_questions" ? Edit your question to have more details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4464/discussion-between-bilash-saha-and-tvalent2)